# Lighthouse returned error: NO_FCP on nginx reverse proxy

Tags: node.js, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have an express server running behind nginx reverse proxy and Certbot for certification. All my non-www traffic is redirected to www and https but on google page speed non-www version gives the following error "Lighthouse returned error: NO_FCP"

This is for a new Server deployed on AWS EC2 with nodejs installed.

```js
server {

  server_name www.compropertee.com compropertee.com;

  location / {
        proxy_pass https://localhost:3000/;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
  }

    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.compropertee.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.compropertee.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot


}
server {
    if ($host = compropertee.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


  listen 80;
  listen [::]:80;

  server_name compropertee.com;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot
}

all non-www and www requests should be working in google speed test.
```